# How to list all values that can be sent as keyword arguments in seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, keyword-argument

For example, when passing `kde_kws` in `sns.displot` as below

```
sns.distplot(df['Award_Amount'],kde_kws={'shade':True}) #Works fine
sns.distplot(df['Award_Amount'],kde_kws={'fill':True})  #AttributeError
```

`'shade'` is recognised as an attribute and works but `'fill'` throws attribute error.

I did not find anything in [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) or `help(sns.distplot)`

Is there a way to list out all possible values that I can send as Keywords Arguments?

Comment: the doc for the `kde_kws` arg links to https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html#seaborn.kdeplot

Comment: so, whatever Parameters that can be sent to `sns.kdeplot` can be sent as a dictionary in kde_kws. Correct?

Comment: Based on the docs, Yes